# How to know if android emulator is fully loaded

Tags: android, bash, adb, genymotion

So we can check the following two

`adb get-state`, will show as device if it's turned on.

`adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim`, will show as stopped if it's finished the boot animation.

How do i check if it's on the main screen and has loaded/rendered everything successfully.

Right now I have a sleep 30 and i'm hoping for the best and that it hasn't crashed in the meantime. I am writing this in `bash`, so a shell command to check would be appreciated it anyone knows.

Comment: just monitor the `logcat` output until you get the `ActivityManager` message about finishing loading the launcher

Comment: The property `init.svc.bootanim = 'stopped'` is set once bootanimation has exit. By me, it's a reliable approach to know when the lock screen/home `Activity` has been rendered. Do you encounter any issues within these two system events?

Comment: Yes, i have a problem because my emulator will open so the state will show `device`, however right after it will also show that the `init.svc.bootanim` is stopped for a couple of seconds before it actually begins the boot animation. I am not sure why this happens.